# Porting gcc versus Visual compiler: char arrays

Tags: c, gcc, recursion

I found out one interesting approach to define in stack buffer without using dynamic allocation; I guess allocation is happening from call stack.

Syntax looks like this (where `modlen` is a variable, not a constant):

```
void vlc_vaLog(vlc_object_t *obj, int type, const char *module,
               const char *format, va_list args)
{
    ...

    char modulebuf[modlen + 1];
```

The Visual C++ compiler does not support such syntax directly, but there exists similar kind of function called `_alloca`, which can dynamically allocate space from stack, without the need to free that allocation.

I have some bad experience with that function, particularly when I have done some Unicode porting using such function + multiple time recursion could crash application because of excessive use of call stack. (Stack overflow)

Also it does not need recursion in itself; you just need to enter a multiple times same or similar function to overflow the stack.

What would you recommend - to write some instructions to developers on how to use such call stack allocation nicely without recursive call or try to avoid such misuse of call stack?

So my question here is basically: Write an instructions to developers who use such odd syntax why not to use it, or write instructions to developers how to use such in-stack allocations correctly.

Is there any difference in behavior if I'll use for windows port

```
char* modulebuf = _alloca(modLen +1);
```

Will it work identically as in gcc ?

I prefer justified answer preferably with real life experience on such syntax.

Comment: This is called VLA and it is part of the C99. I'm not sure what the exact question is, but it's often a good idea to avoid VLA and `alloca` unless you are very careful.  Neither option handles failures gracefully.

Comment: Are you looking to a feature similar to VLA or `alloca` function that allocates memory for automatic storage but which is not VLA or `alloca`?